# A set of n integers is a complete residue modulo n if no two elements are congruent mod n.

Tags: number-theory, proof-verification, congruence-relations

A set of n integers is a complete residue modulo n if no two elements are congruent mod n.

I understand the theorem but how do I go about proving it? Any help would be appreciated!

My attempt.

Theorem 3.17 states

Let n be a natural number. Any set {a1,a2,...,an} of n integers for which no two are congruent is a complete residue system modulo n.

Intuitively, this makes sense, if no two are congruent, then they all have distinct remainders .

Proof by contradiction applying the pigeon hole principal(have never used it in a proof).

Suppose we have a set of n integers, call it 
A={a1,a2,...an} 
in which no two are congruent modulo n and suppose we have a residue set 
R={r1,r2...rn-1} 
where we have less than n residues.

Since a1 is not congruent mod n to any ai for  1

Since a2 is not congruent mod n to any ai for  2

Now, an is not congruent to any ai mod n for any   1<=i<=n-1, so by the D.A, an=n(qn)+rn, which implies that an is congruent to rn mod n, but this is impossible since R has fewer than n elements(remainders), so an is congruent to some ai for some n<=i<=1 , but this contradicts that an is not congruent to any ai.

Comment: This is usually called a "complete residue system", and often it's *defined* to be a set of $n$ integers with no two congruent mod $n$.  If you've been asked to prove this, you probably have been provided some other definition of "complete residue system".  What definition do you have?

Comment: Pigeon-hole principle?

Comment: My book says that each integer( in Z) in congruent to only one and only one element in my set of n integers!

Comment: It follows using division with remainder to show that each element is congruent to a unique one of the numbers {0,1, ..., n-1} and then using division with remainder to say each integer is congruent to a unique one of these.

Comment: Ok, so what you're saying is, each remainder will be unique? And thus all of the integers are not congruent to each other at all?

Comment: I wouldn't say "and thus all of the integers are not congruent to each other at all", since it makes it sound like a deduction.  That's not a deduction, but rather a restatement of your hypothesis that "no two elements are congruent modulo n".  But yes, that hypothesis implies that "each remainder will be unique."

Comment: The actual proof depends *highly* in how formal you are being (for instance, what is the definition of "A set of $n$ integers?") But at heart, the argument is division algorithm and pigeonhole principle.

Comment: So I've never really worked with the pigeon hole principal, to be honest I don't think I'd be able to work with it. I can totally do a handwavy proof of this, but using the Pidgeon hole principal would kill me

Comment: The pigeonhole principle is actually maybe the easiest proof technique to describe that there is.  (Using it can be tricky sometimes, but here there's no trick.)  Don't shy away from using it.  Let your set of n integers be the pigeons, and let the set of remainders they give when dividing by n be the pigeon holes.  Assume, to reach a contradiction, that this set of remainders is not {0, 1, 2, ..., n-1}, so it has fewer then n elements.  Now you can apply the pigeonhole principle and reach a contradiction.

Comment: I don't see where you use the pigeonhole principle.  I'd change the following: let R be specifically the set of remainders when you divide each of $a_1$, $\ldots$, $a_n$ by n.  Assume, to reach a contradiction, that the set R has fewer than $n$ elements.  Then, using the pigeon hole principle with the elements of R as the holes and the elements $a_1$, $\ldots$, $a_n$ as the pigeons, you can decide that...

Answer (score 1):

If v = r mod n and w = r mod n then v = w mod n.

By definition a complete residue modulo n is *some* set of n integers {$r_i$} where no two are congruent to each other.  What we need to prove is that *any* other such set {$s_i$} of n integers is also a complete residue.

Well {$r_i$} being a complete residue means, each $s_i = r_j \mod n$ for some $r_j$.  Another $s_k$ where $s_k \ne s_i$ is congruent to some $r_l$.  If $r_l = r_j$ the $s_i$ an $s_k$ are congruent to each other.  Thus each $s_k$ is congruent to a different $r_j$ and thus each $s_i$ is in a unique congruency class and as {$r_i$} represents all classes and there is a direct correspondence  between {$r_i$} and {$s_i$}, {$s_i$} is a complete residue.